# how to repair broken (jersey) links in Maven

Tags: maven, jersey

Whenever I try to run tutorials/examples on jersey I seem to get stuck. For example the following two:

- //github.com/jesperfj/jax-rs-upload-file.git
- //github.com/jamesward/jaxrsbars.git

and what's worse, the error seems to depend on my repository, i.e. on the history of running other (similar) projects, e.g. the following Maven Archetype:

- com.sun.jersey.archetypes:jersey-quickstart-grizzly2

I've tried to describe my findings in detail below. My questions:

- Can I (new to Maven and Jersey) hope to repair broken links on a project that I do not understand and if yes, what would be the typical strategy ?
- what is causing these "CHECKSUM FAILED" errors ?
- is this a typical issue for jersey and/or is it related to the SUN-issue described [here](http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-coping-with-sun-jars.html) ?

any help either on getting the examples to work or on a better understanding of what is going wrong, is highly appreciated ?

What I did:

I first delete my local .m2/repository and run `mvn package` on the jax-rs-upload-example :

```
(...)
Downloading: http://maven.glassfish.org/content/groups/glassfish/net/java/jvnet-parent/1/jvnet-parent-1.pom
185b downloaded  (jvnet-parent-1.pom)
[WARNING] *** CHECKSUM FAILED 
(...)
[INFO] Error building POM (may not be this project's POM).
(...)
Reason: Cannot find parent: net.java:jvnet-parent for project: com.sun.jersey:jersey-project:pom:1.9.1 for project com.sun.jersey:jersey-project:pom:1.9.1
```

When I then do a `mvn package` on either the other example or on the quickstart-archetype I see similar `net.java.jvnet-parent` errors. However, If I then delete my repository, and rebuild the quickstart-archetype, it now builds and runs. And if I now build the two examples, I see again a number of CHECKSUM FAILED messages, finally resulting in the following errors:

**jax-rs-upload**

```
[ERROR] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Compilation failure

error: error reading /home/rafel/.m2/repository/com/sun/jersey/jersey-server/1.9.1/jersey-server-1.9.1.jar; error in opening zip file
error: error reading /home/rafel/.m2/repository/com/sun/jersey/jersey-core/1.9.1/jersey-core-1.9.1.jar; error in opening zip file
```

**jaxrsbars**

```
[INFO] Compilation failure

error: error reading /home/rafel/.m2/repository/org/glassfish/hk2/osgi-resource-locator/1.0.1/osgi-resource-locator-1.0.1.jar; error in opening zip file
error: error reading /home/rafel/.m2/repository/org/glassfish/hk2/external/javax.inject/1.6.32/javax.inject-1.6.32.jar; error in opening zip file
error: error reading /home/rafel/.m2/repository/org/glassfish/hk2/external/asm-all-repackaged/1.6.32/asm-all-repackaged-1.6.32.jar; error in opening zip file
```